# Link to privileges is gone from the profile

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, privileges

Before the profile update, there was a link to the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). This link was useful to loop up what you can do and when you would be granted a new privilege.

That link was replaced by the following:

[image: New privileges screen]

This is beautiful, but I can't see everything I have gained in the past and how far I still have to go until becoming a *trusted user*.

Also, from that link you have to then click on the bread crumbs to be able to get to the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) list.

Comment: It's still in Help Center > View a full list of privileges you can earn

Comment: @jonrsharpe the point I was trying to make is that it was so easy to get to the privileges list  before where now it's not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's less accessible now, but it's still there. In your user profile, click on the **Edit Profile & Settings** tab. On the left there is a list. The One on the bottom says **Privileges**. Click on it, and it will take you to the original page.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful to know where that link is. and I guess that its ok for that link to be be front and center

Comment: You can also click on the progress bar showing your next privilege and click "learn more" to show the help page for your next privilege. There's link at the top of that page to the privileges list.